# Add Zip file to project and get location

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a zipfile called test.zip that I want to add to my xcode project. This zip file will be decompressed the very first time (and only time) the application is launched. Usually when I add files, I just grab them and drag them into my xcode project. I am using the following code
from this [libary](https://github.com/samsoffes/ssziparchive)

```
NSString *zipPath = @"path_to_your_zip_file";
NSString *destinationPath = @"path_to_the_folder_where_you_want_it_unzipped";
[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:zipPath toDestination:destinationPath];
```

Now if I have added the test.zip file by just dragging it into my project, what would my zipPath be? Similar, can anyone also tell me where the proper location to unzip the files would be? I would assume somewhere in the document directory.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save your file this way, make sure you give correct filename for  **youzipfilename**

```
NSString *zipPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"youzipfilename" ofType:@"zip"];
NSString *appDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:zipPath toDestination:appDirectory];
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. Thank you. Last question,how would I write to the library instead of documentDirectory? H2CO3 noted that the document directory can be read by the user. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I changed the code a bit, now it saves in a different place. Not in the documents directory now in ApplicationSupportDirectory. This is the place where we save the files which should be hidden to the user.

Comment: Thank you. I accepted your answer but out of curiosity, should the destination path contain "destzipfile.zip"? Should it not just be the location of the NSApplicationSupportDirectory?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. According to the Library you use, it's only the destination directory we should provide.